# SIngle RxJava how to extract object

Tags: java, rx-java, system.reactive, rx-android

I can think of two ways to get the value from Single

```
Single<HotelResult> observableHotelResult = 
                            apiObservables.getHotelInfoObservable(requestBody);

final HotelResult[] hotelResults = new HotelResult[1];
    singleHotelResult
            .subscribe(hotelResult -> {
                hotelResults[0] = hotelResult;
            });
```

Or

```
    final HotelResult hotelResult = singleHotelResult
                                    .toBlocking()
                                    .value();
```

It's written in the documentation that we should avoid using .toBlocking method.

So is there any better way to get value

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/3956

Answer (score 7):

When we use `toBlocking` then we get result immediately. When we use `subscribe` then result is obtained asynchronously.

```
Single<HotelResult> observableHotelResult = 
    apiObservables.getHotelInfoObservable(requestBody);

final HotelResult[] hotelResults = new HotelResult[1];
singleHotelResult.subscribe(hotelResult -> {
    hotelResults[0] = hotelResult;
});
// hotelResults[0] may be not initialized here yet
// println not show result yet (if operation for getting hotel info is long)
System.out.println(hotelResults[0]);
```

For blocking case:

```
final HotelResult hotelResult = singleHotelResult.toBlocking().value();
// hotelResult has value here but program workflow will stuck here until API is being called.
```

`toBlocking` helps in the cases when you are using Observables in "normal" code where you need to have the result in place.

`subscribe` helps you for example in Android application when you can set some actions in `subscribe` like show result on the page, make button disabled etc.

Comment: I want to wait until the result is fetched. So even in case of subscribe I haven't mentioned any scheduler so that will also be a synchronous(in my opinion) call. For my use case I am going with blocking observable only.

Answer (score 7):

Even it is not recommended to block it (you should subscribe), in RxJava v2 the method for blocking is blockingGet(), it returns the object immediately.